# SQLAlchemy introspection of ORM classes/objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, introspection

I am looking for a way to introspect SQLAlchemy ORM classes/entities to determine the types and other constraints (like maximum lengths) of an entity's properties.

For example, if I have a declarative class:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "USER_TABLE"

    id = sa.Column(sa.types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullname = sa.Column(sa.types.String(100))
    username = sa.Column(sa.types.String(20), nullable=False)
    password = sa.Column(sa.types.String(20), nullable=False)
    created_timestamp = sa.Column(sa.types.DateTime, nullable=False)
```

I would want to be able to find out that the '`fullname`' field should be a String with a maximum length of 100, and is nullable. And the '`created_timestamp`' field is a DateTime and is not nullable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like:

```
table = User.__table__
field = table.c["fullname"]
print "Type", field.type
print "Length", field.type.length
print "Nullable", field.nullable
```

**EDIT:**

The upcoming 0.8 version has a [New Class Inspection System](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/08Migration#NewClassInspectionSystem):

> New Class Inspection System
>
> Status: completed, needs docs
>
> Lots of SQLAlchemy users are writing systems that require the ability
>   to inspect the attributes of a mapped class, including being able to
>   get at the primary key columns, object relationships, plain
>   attributes, and so forth, typically for the purpose of building
>   data-marshalling systems, like JSON/XML conversion schemes and of
>   course form libraries galore.
>
> Originally, the Table and Column model were the original inspection
>   points, which have a well-documented system. While SQLAlchemy ORM
>   models are also fully introspectable, this has never been a fully
>   stable and supported feature, and users tended to not have a clear
>   idea how to get at this information.
>
> 0.8 has a plan to produce a consistent, stable and fully documented API for this purpose, which would provide an inspection system that
>   works on classes, instances, and possibly other things as well. While
>   many elements of this system are already available, the plan is to
>   lock down the API including various accessors available from such
>   objects as Mapper, InstanceState, and MapperProperty:

(follow the link for more info)

Comment: I've been spending so much time with `declarative` that I forgot all about looking at the underlying columns. Thanks!