# SQLAlchemy: inspection of column type size gives odd result

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to query a column for its *maximum* possible size of data (in bytes) that can be stored in it? For example, say I declare a column using

```
content = Column(LargeBinary)
```

then how can I query information about `content`? Following the [inspection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html?highlight=inspect#sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect) approach suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784986/sqlalchemy-introspection-of-orm-classes-objects) question:

```
table = File.__table__
field = table.c["content"]
print("max=" + field.type.length)
```

I get a `max=None`, whereas I would have expected this to be `max=65535` considering `field.type=BLOB`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, the maximum length of a column is **dialect specific** and this information is not stored inside the sqlalchemy sources. Though, depending on the backend, you can get it dynamically. For example, for `mysql` you can retrieve it from [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html):

```
q = select(["CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"]).select_from("INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS").where(
    and_("table_name = '%s'" % File.__tablename__,
         "table_schema = '%s'" % schema,
         "column_name = '%s'" % column_name))
result = session.execute(q)
print(result.first()[0])  # tested - prints 65535
```

<sup>I bet there is a more beautiful way to write the query.</sup>

See also:

- [Determine max length allowed in a column in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990385/determine-max-length-allowed-in-a-column-in-mysql)
- [How to check if PostgreSQL schema exists using SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346076/how-to-check-if-postgresql-schema-exists-using-sqlalchemy) (information_schema query example)

---

`field.type.length` refers to the user-defined maximum length which is [initialized to `None` if not provided explicitly](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py#L810-L904):

```
def __init__(self, length=None):
    self.length = length
```

And since you are not providing the `length` argument, you are getting `None`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Querying the DB directly using `q` above gives me the correct datatype sizes as defined [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html). For the Alchemy implementation, I've now used an artificial limit by setting `self.length` which maps into a SQL MEDIUMBLOB.